# SPA how often to send Content Security Policy header?

Tags: single-page-application, content-security-policy

If I have a single page application index.html and wish to set the CSP header, can I get away with only sending it on the index.html page header or do i have to set it in the header of every js/htm file etc.

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: CSP is meant for any htm files that are loaded, so just index.htm and any iframes. in a spa other htm is loaded via js already subject to csp.